# Laravel 5.3 redirecting banned users on login

Tags: php, laravel

Hi there I am trying to redirect any user who tries to login who has a ban_status ! = 0

I am wondering what the best way for me to do this, I was thinking just to log them out and redirect them to a banned page but I only want banned users accessing this page, or adding a error on the form to say 'you are banned' etc. Here is my code currently:

public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

```
    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    if ($lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->credentials($request);

    if ($this->guard()->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        if ($this->guard()->user()->ban_status === 0) { // Check if the user is banned or not before allowing login
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }
        else {

            $this->guard()->logout();

            $request->session()->flush();

            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return redirect('/banned'); // If the user banned_status is set to 1, then they will be redirected to a banned page.
        }
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if (! $lockedOut) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Comment: You could probably write middleware that checks if user is banned and if so, it redirects them to proper page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method wouldn't stop the users from accessing your other routes directly if they know your route names.

You could stop this by adding a middleware, protecting all your other routes and if the middle ware fails to validate, redirecting the user to a banned page.

See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

Comment: To get around this I have @if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->ban_status != 0)

{{ Auth::logout() }}

endif at the top of every page?

Comment: That is a lot of redundant code, if you add middleware, it's only a few lines and you can remove all of that...

Comment: Would it not be easier to modify the auth middleware to check for an extra condition?

Comment: I would suggest using the Auth middleware when needing to protect routes. You do not need to modify the Auth middleware, because you simply do not want to allow banned users to log in at all. Instead, do not allow banned users to log in as you have in your code, and attach an Auth middleware to any route you need to be logged in for.